# how to save data of current activity while going back to parent activity?

Tags: android

I have an Activity_1 after a lot of steps, say  Activity_2 > Activity_3 .I am coming back to Activity_1 and then again go to Activity_2 but this time I need those data to be retained which I saved previously

Comment: activity destroy->Data destroy .  Use a Singleton class to save the data .Although its not traditional flow what you want to do .

Comment: why dont u save the data in shared preference and use when required